# get position of clicked item in recyclerView using dataBinding

Tags: java, android, xml, data-binding

thank you for reading my question,
I've Implemented onClick in recyclerView using dataBinding but I can send the object itself to click function but I need the item position is it possible to get item position in `onClick`?
here is how click is implemented in the recyclerView item:

```
    android:onClick="@{ (v) -> model.click(obj) }"
```

Comment: where is your adapter code? and the model code alseo?

Comment: you can pass your position into the layout from your adapter. In `onBindViewHolder` you can call `holder.binding.setVariable(BR.itemPosition, position)`

Answer (score 4):

## Use Interface

Create Interface

```
interface ItemClickListener{
    void itemClicked(int position)
}
```

Use ItemClickListener and Integer in XML and call interface method on `onClick()` like this

```
android:onClick="@{()->itemClickListener.itemClicked(position)}"
```

Demo XML snippet my_item.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   <data>
      <variable
          name="itemClickListener"
          type="ItemClickListener" />
       <variable
          name="position"
          type="Integer"/>
    </data>
    <LinerLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/offer_image"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:onClick="@{()->itemClickListener.itemClicked(position)}"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Set ItemClickListener and Position in Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

      private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

      public MyAdapter(Context){
          itemClickListener = (ItemClickListener)context;
      }

      @Override
      public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

          MyItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
            R.layout.my_item, parent, false);
          return new MyViewHolder(binding);
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OfferViewHolder holder, int position) {
          holder.bind(position);
       }

       class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            private MyItemBinding binding;

            public OfferViewHolder(@NonNull ItemOfferBinding binding) {
               super(binding.getRoot());
               this.binding = binding;
            }

            private void bind(int position){
               binding.setItemClickListener(itemClickListener);    //<----This is important
               binding.setPosition(position);                      //<-- This is important
            }

       }

 }
```

Activity Code

```
MyActicity extends AppCompatActivity{
      
      MyAdapter adapter = new Adapter(this);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's use full thank you @Rohit Singh

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.hTextview_Score.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
}
```

make click of your view in OnBindViewHolder and position is position of view

Comment: the point is i want to use databinding and add click function there so im not going to use this way.

Comment: As i said using databinding!

Comment: oh sorry i didnt read question carefully using  databinding you can see here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46874441/recyclerview-item-click-listener-with-databinding

Answer (score 0):

There is an exposed property that you can use inside ViewHolder, when using databinding.
Just call `adapterPosition`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `adapterPosition` in view holder to pass item position to ItemView and then you can pass `itemPosition` to `android:onClick="@{ (v) -> model.click(obj, itemPosition) }"`

```
 class GeneralHolder<DataModel, ClickListner>(
        private val binding: ViewDataBinding,
        val listener: ClickListner
    ) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(data: DataModel) {
            binding.setVariable(BR.item, data)
            binding.setVariable(BR.presenter, listener)
            binding.setVariable(BR.itemPosition, adapterPosition)
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

use getBindingAdapterPosition()

Comment: please read my question more carefully, this won't work.